# compare two string value in same array based on each char . this result only showing Last OUT value why

Tags: c++, string, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void Calc( const string, const string , string&);

void Dbf(const string,const string, string&);


int main ()
{

    string OUT;

    string A[]={"10","12"};

    string j = A[0];
    string k = A[1];

     Calc(j,k,OUT);

        cout<< "ODD  :"<<j<<endl;
        cout<< "EVEN :"<<k<<endl;
        cout<< "OUT  :"<<OUT<<endl;
        cout<< "OUT  :"<<OUT<<endl;

// this result only showing Last OUT value why pls help

  return 0;
}

void Calc( const string J ,const string K, string& Out){

        int OD_L = J.length();
        int EV_L = K.length();
        int D = (OD_L - 1);
        int E = (EV_L - 1);

            for(int io = D ; io >= 0; io-- ){

            string OD(1, J[io]);
            string EV(1, K[io]);

            Dbf( OD , EV, Out);

            }
}

void Dbf(const string S_odd, const string S_even, string& p_Out){
    if(S_odd == S_even){

        p_Out = " yes ";

    }else{

        p_Out = " no " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like that `Calc` function will go kaboom if those strings are different lengths, especially if J is longer than K.

Comment: i already have code for that problem is Calc Function only showing last Loop result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to compare two string to produce long result of " yes " and " no ". In Dbf you should append string to p_Out, not overwrite it. Try:

```
void Dbf(const string S_odd, const string S_even, string& p_Out){
    if(S_odd == S_even){
        p_Out += " yes ";
    }
    else{
        p_Out += " no " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: same result .  problem is Calc Function only showing last Loop result

Comment: When I use this Dbf function I get "OUT  : no  yes ". You get the same?